# Customize WooCommerce Checkout Fields and Columns

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using WPExplorer's Total theme: [You should be able to click this sentence to open the Total Theme from WPExplorer. You'll need to add something to your cart and get to the checkout page for the rest of this...](http://totaltheme.wpengine.com/base/checkout/) I've asked the theme author for some help, but apparently, this is a WooCommerce issue.
Ok, fine. So I crack open my TeamTreeHouse account and go through as much as I can possibly find.  No luck.

Now if you have the theme opened up, you'll see that the default checkout page puts ALL of the `woocommerce_checkout_billing` fields on the left and then all of the `woocommerce_checkout_shipping` fields on the right.

Now, if your store has almost no products that require shipping like virtual products and downloadable products, then there's a problem:

The checkout page is INCREDIBLY lopsided. There are tons of fields running down the left of the page and almost never any fields on the right-hand side of the page. What I'm attempting to do is make the `checkout_billing` fields be one left, one right, (new line), next one left, next one right, (new line), left then right again, then (if needed) display the "Ship to A Different Address" toggle appears.  And then IF **and only when** the additional `woocommerce_checkout_shipping` fields are needed they again appear left, right, (new line) left then right, (new line) left & right.

The end result is that the checkout page has **SYMMETRY** on the forms *instead of all being down the left side*

The file from Woo that controls the checkout page is https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/checkout/form-checkout.php#L33 and starting at line 33 we see this:

```
<div class="col2-set" id="customer_details">
        <div class="col-1">
            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_billing' ); ?>
        </div>

        <div class="col-2">
            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_shipping' ); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

*What* do I need to change to simply make the fields appear 1 left, 1 right, new line, 1 left, 1 right, on and on for the checkout_billing, then again in the `checkout_shipping` 1 left, 1 right, new line, on and on and on?

Thanks!

Comment: "I've been told that asking an incorrect question on here is apparently the kiss of death and social flogging is quite possible" Ha! It isn't as bad as all that, but certain things are off topic and you'd be surprised the sheer number of truly terrible questions. Closing all that down helps get actual answers to the good questions.

Answer (score 1):

This seems more like a pure CSS question to me. Something like the following would be a start (assuming I understood what you were describing) and could be further customized. Use your browser's developer tools to inspect the elements and live-test their style rules.

First, we remove the 2 main columns. Then, we split the inputs into columns. Note, this doesn't include any responsive layouts.

```
.woocommerce .woocommerce-checkout .col2-set .col-1 {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
}

.woocommerce form .form-row {
    margin-right: 4%;
    float: left;
    width: 48%;
}

.woocommerce form .form-row-last {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: I have added form-checkout.php file to the Total Child theme folder http://prntscr.com/8ihd88 & changed the class on line 33 of the form-checkout.php https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/checkout/form-checkout.php#L33
to "form-row-wide" http://prntscr.com/8iheox
Obviously, that's wrong.  My goal there was to double check that the folder was pulling the correct file. Now that I've given myself a teeny bit of confidence :-) let's move on.

What's the CSS that will simply make any form fields go one on the left, the next field on the right, then go to the new line?

Comment: I think I left some width and float rules out. Try with the updated code. It isn't as easy as you describe because of woo's markup but I think that should get you close.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/8isyq6 and that's the weird part... no matter what I seem to add, change, or modify, it still sets things into two columns ~ which is kinda the goal, but not quite like that.  I'm sure your css is far more advanced that what I've learned through the years. Yet regardless of what anyone tries to do, the right side of the checkout page is still having the (rarely used) "ship to a different address".

Comment: Don't forget that these style rules need to come *after* the WooCommerce stylesheet (and/or possibly also after the theme's stylesheet). Otherwise Woo's rules will be applied.

Comment: Dangit with a caPital d!!!  Ya ever have one of those vague de ja vu moments when you're browsing the innerwebs?  I finally clicked on your username and my cranium finally connected the seemingly random dots.
Young lady, YOU ARE AWESOME!!! ;-)  I've been reading your AWESOMENESS for a while!!! 
Ok, enough of that.  I really do wish I could magically catapult my learning to where you're at! Now I realize (yet another thing to learn) that all these CSS files get loaded in a priority.  awesome. HA!

Comment: Thanks Brad! that's really kind of you to say. If anything really catapulted my learning along it was probably answering questions for people in forums... first for the Thematic theme and now here for WooCommerce. Does loading the CSS later solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

@helgatheviking provides a good answer, but this will change the row elements throughout the whole site.

Use the `.page-id` class with the checkout page ID to prevent issues with other pages that use the `.woocommerce row` classes.

```css
.page-id-yourpageid .woocommerce .woocommerce-checkout .col2-set .col-1 {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
}

.page-id-yourpageid .woocommerce form .form-row {
    margin-right: 4%;
    float: left;
    width: 48%;
}

.page-id-yourpageid .woocommerce form .form-row-last {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```